# firebase onCall cloud function not returning the results

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My callable function looks like this:

```
exports.function = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    let result1, result2;

    async function function1() {
        return 1;
    }

    async function function2() {
        return 2;
    }

    return Promise.all([
        result1 = function1(),
        result2 = function2()
    ])
    .then(() => {
        console.log(result1);
        console.log(result2);
        return {
            result1: result1,
            result2: result2
        }
    }) 
})
```

The result1 and result2 I get at the client side do not have any value but only have a field called domain. What is wrong with my cloud function?

**log output**

```
Promise {
  1,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } } 

Promise {
  2,
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a field called domain"?  What is the log output of this code?  Please edit the question to also show the client code and the output it generates.  There should be enough information in your question that anyone can reproduce and observe the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Just added the log output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are capturing the promises returned by `function1` and `function2` and trying to send them directly to the client.  That's not going to work.  You will need to get their resolved values in the callback on the promise returned by `Promise.all()`.

```
    return Promise.all([
        function1(),
        function2()
    ])
    .then((result1, result2) => {
        console.log(result1);
        console.log(result2);
        return {
            result1: result1,
            result2: result2
        }
    })
```

Note that you don't even need to declare result1 and result2 at the higher scope.